# UPDATE the result which retrieved from a SELECT in same Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update the "payments" table's "payment_status" column to '1' in the RESULT of following SELECT query but within a single Query. Please help me.

```
SELECT * FROM payments p
INNER JOIN invoice i
ON i.invoice_number = p.invoiceGRN_id
WHERE i.invoice_status = '2' AND i.payment_type = 'Credit'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do an `UPDATE` with an `INNER JOIN`

```
UPDATE payments p
INNER JOIN invoice i
ON i.invoice_number = p.invoiceGRN_id
SET p.payment_status = 1
WHERE i.invoice_status = '2' AND i.payment_type = 'Credit'
```

Alternatively you could do something like this (which is less efficient, but more directly answers your question):

```
UPDATE payments 
SET payment_status = 1 
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT p.id FROM payments p
    INNER JOIN invoice i
    ON i.invoice_number = p.invoiceGRN_id
    WHERE i.invoice_status = '2' AND i.payment_type = 'Credit'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
UPDATE payments SET payment_status = 1 WHERE payment_ID in (
  SELECT payment_ID FROM payments p
  INNER JOIN invoice i
  ON i.invoice_number = p.invoiceGRN_id
  WHERE i.invoice_status = '2' AND i.payment_type = 'Credit')
```